# Stop showing add onBackpressed

Tags: android, startapp

I am using [startApp-SDK](https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/Documentation/wiki/Android-InApp-&-InApp-Plus-Documentation) . on pressing back button from mainActivity. it shows an add by default. I want to stop showing that add on Backpressed. MainActivity extends from TabActivity and contains three tabs on pressing back from any of them show ads. I have override onBackpressed. in all of them. but still showing those ads.

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

and also tried some other way around but problem don't solve ..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: search for startAppAd.showAd();
  startAppAd.loadAd();
if you find in onbackPressed then just comment it

Comment: See this: https://github.com/StartApp-SDK/StartApp_InApp_SDK_Example

Comment: I have included a SDK. it is showing adds onBackpressed by Default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find the solution to my question . May be it help someone else..

whlile declaring StartappAd

```
StartAppSDK.init(this, "105605040","205467351", false);  // true for showing adds.
```

//NOTE: If you don't wish your application to display ads when pressing the Home button,Back Button simply pass false in the last parameter